# can't open python console with docker in pycharm

Tags: python, docker, pycahrm

version - PyCharm 2023.1 (Professional Edition)

Build #PY-231.8109.197, built on March 29, 2023

after define docker interpreter I can run scrips from within pycharm, but when I try to debug the script or just open a regular console I get this error

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --host=host.docker.internal --port=38691 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 570, in <module>

    pydevconsole.start_client(host, port)

  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 482, in start_client

    client, server_transport = make_rpc_client(client_service, host, port)

  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_comm/pydev_rpc.py", line 11, in make_rpc_client

    client_transport, server_transport = open_transports_as_client((host, port))

  File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_comm/pydev_transport.py", line 231, in open_transports_as_client

    client_socket.connect(addr)

socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Couldn't connect to console process.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

any help?